# Why is this gemfile not working

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

UPDATES:
now that I have installed all the dependencies for RedCloth, when I run the old gemfile it says that I need to use an earlier version of bundler to run it 1.0.10 instead of 1.11.2 which is the version that I needed for RedCloth. Here are some of my errors

Here is the file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem install Redcloth -v '4.2.9'
```

which gives me this error

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: compile error - syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
gem install Redcloth -v '4.2.9'
                         ^. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/adamalloy/adamralloy.github.io/Gemfile:2
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem install Redcloth -v '4.2.9'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

how am I supposed to format this? what confuses me is that I get no error from

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

Which is what I am supposed to run to set up jekyll. bundler installs the gem for a while but encounters an error when it needs to install Redcloth. This is my first time using ruby so I am confused.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'redcloth', '4.2.9'
```

You are not supposed to write `gem install Redcloth -v '4.2.9'` inside your `Gemfile`. You can do so from your terminal.